# XSLT - Generate unique id fora each distinct value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to generate a unique id for each distinct value using XSLT-1.0. I have a XSMLstructure and every time when I find the same value in  tag I would like to generate a unique id into the output tag .

Input XML:

```
<EMPLOYEES>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <NAME>AAA</NAME>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <NAME>AAA</NAME>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <NAME>BBB</NAME>
    </EMPLOYEE>
</EMPLOYEES>
```

Desired output:

```
<RESULT>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <GROUP>1</GROUP>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <GROUP>1</GROUP>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <GROUP>2</GROUP>
    </EMPLOYEE>
</RESULT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variation of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="emp-by-name" match="EMPLOYEE" use="NAME" />

<xsl:template match="/EMPLOYEES">
    <RESULT>
        <xsl:for-each select="EMPLOYEE">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
                <GROUP>
                    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('emp-by-name', NAME)[1])"/>
                </GROUP>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </RESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The format of the unique id depends on the processor you use: for example, using `libxslt` you might see a result like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULT>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <GROUP>idm86101615952</GROUP>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <GROUP>idm86101615952</GROUP>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <GROUP>idm86101613584</GROUP>
  </EMPLOYEE>
</RESULT>
```

while `MSXML` can produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RESULT>
<EMPLOYEE>
<ID>1</ID>
<GROUP>IDOECYH2JCFIENET332KVV31ACSEILRTQLIHKWOCNC1WN5QJBD3AH</GROUP>
</EMPLOYEE>
<EMPLOYEE>
<ID>2</ID>
<GROUP>IDOECYH2JCFIENET332KVV31ACSEILRTQLIHKWOCNC1WN5QJBD3AH</GROUP>
</EMPLOYEE>
<EMPLOYEE>
<ID>3</ID>
<GROUP>IDZZBORVA3LQGFPDQLO51JC1X1JDCTYLF430BB43GE1YQ1D54SHZSB</GROUP>
</EMPLOYEE>
</RESULT>
```